# proxies do not work with aiohttp requests?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

So I've been experimenting with web scraping with aiohttp, and I ran into this issue where whenever I use a proxy, the code within the session.get doesn't run. I've looked all over the internet and couldn't find a solution.

```
import asyncio
import time 
import aiohttp
from aiohttp.client import ClientSession
import random
failed = 0
success = 0
proxypool = []
with open("proxies.txt", "r") as jsonFile:
    lines = jsonFile.readlines()
    for i in lines:
        x = i.split(":")
        proxypool.append("http://"+x[2]+":"+x[3].rstrip()+"@"+x[0]+":"+x[1])

async def download_link(url:str,session:ClientSession):
    global failed
    global success
    proxy = proxypool[random.randint(0, len(proxypool))]
    print(proxy)
    async with session.get(url, proxy=proxy) as response:
        
        if response.status != 200:
            failed +=1
        else:
            success +=1

        result = await response.text()
        print(result)
        
        
        

async def download_all(urls:list):
    my_conn = aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=1000)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=my_conn,trust_env=True) as session:
        tasks = []
        for url in urls:
            task = asyncio.ensure_future(download_link(url=url,session=session))
            tasks.append(task)
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks,return_exceptions=True) # the await must be nest inside of the session

url_list = ["https://www.google.com"]*100
start = time.time()
asyncio.run(download_all(url_list))
end = time.time()
print(f'download {len(url_list)-failed} links in {end - start} seconds')
print(failed, success)
```

Here is the problem though, the code works fine on my mac. However, when I try to run the exact same code on windows, it doesn't run. It also works fine without proxies, but as soon as I add them, it doesn't work.

At the end, you can see that I print failed and succeeded. On my mac it will output 0, 100, whereas on my windows computer, it will print 0,0 -  This proves that that code isn't running (Also, nothing is printed)

The proxies I am using are paid proxies, and they work normally if I use `requests.get()`. Their format is `"http://user:pass@ip:port"`

I have also tried just using "http://ip:port" then using BasicAuth to carry the user and password, but this does not work either.

I've seen that many other people have had this problem, however the issue never seems to get solved.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: What Python and aiohttp version are you using?

Comment: Python version is 3.10.5, aiohttp version is 3.7.4

Comment: Try to upgrade the aiohttp module to the latest. According to the documentation: https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_advanced.html (bottom) Python 3.10 needs aiohttp 3.8 or higher in order to support TLS in proxies, as I understand it.

Comment: I just updated my aiohttp to 3.8.1, still encountering the same issue.  don't believe I need tls is needed. But thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some more testing and researching I found the issue, I needed to add `ssl = False`

So the correct way to make the request would be:

```
async with session.get(url, proxy=proxy, ssl = False) as response:
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

`aiohttp` does not trust the `http_proxy` environment variable by default.

```
async with ClientSession(trust_env=True) as session:
```

https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html